# Is it known you shouldn't name methods starting with 'get' when using @ConfigurationProperties on a Spring @Component

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose a simple Spring Boot @Component like this one:

```java
    @Component
    @Data
    @EnableScheduling
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "demo")
    public class DemoClass {

        private String aString;
        private Long aLong;

        @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${demo.delay}")
        void getSomething() {
            System.out.println("aString = " + aString);
            System.out.println("aLong = " + aLong.toString());
        }
    }
```

It will not start throwing

> ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'demoClass': Could not bind properties to 'DemoClass'

All you need to fix is a *getSomething* method name. Just rename it to *putSomething* for example.
I've lost three hours debugging Spring Boot sources and found it: Spring tries to bind Bean property named *Something*. And the exception occurs.

I know it's a weird practice to name methods starting with *get* if it's not a getter, but is it mentioned somewhere in Spring Docs? Does it say something about guessing properties names from method names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Spring uses the [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) standard to process the configuration properties POJO, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding):

> Such arrangement relies on a default empty constructor and getters and setters are usually mandatory, since binding is through standard Java Beans property descriptors, just like in Spring MVC.